# Enable Hangouts SMS Notification on second user

Tags: sms, notifications

I'm using Android with a main user and a secondary user account.

**How can I enable notifications when I receive a new SMS?**

This notifications are apearing in the main user only.
For the secundary account only when I open Hangouts I can see the unread SMS messages.

I've been looking in the Hangouts settings and can't enable this option.

I'm using a Nexus 5 with Marshmallow 6.

Comment: In Hangouts have you tried settings -> accounts -> tap on the secondary account -> notifications and check the box "Notifications"?

Comment: I think that's the notifications for the hangouts account (that's checked).
But what I want is the SMS notification.
And in the SMS settings I can only choose the sound and the vibration. There's not an option there to turn on or off. 
Don't know if there's another system settings for SMS outside hangouts.